# Trouble accessing html value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript webpage where I define variables by `getElementById` but I can't access everything within the object.

```
const x = document.getElementById('value_x_id')
console.log(x)
```

Which results in

```
<label id="value_x_id" class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInp…led MuiFormLabel-filled" data-shrink="true" value="true">
```

I want to specifically access `value` but it returns as null:
I can successfully access `id` but not any of the other values.

```
console.log(x.id)
```

Results in:

```
value_x_id
```

Comment: `value` is not normally a part of a `label` but, as an attribute, you can get it using `console.log(x.getAttribute('value'))`

Comment: `value` is a custom attribute for `label` elements, it's not reflected to the properties of the element.

Comment: @StephenP Thank you. That fixed it

Comment: `class` can be accessed via `className`; `data-shrink` can be accessed via `dataset.shrink`; `value` can be accessed, as @StephenP says, via `getAttribute('value')`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `value` attribute value, you can use `getAttribute` function.

```js
const x = document.getElementById('value_x_id');
console.log(x.getAttribute('value'));
```

```html
<label id="value_x_id" class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInp?led MuiFormLabel-filled" data-shrink="true" value="true">
```

Comment: Thanks but that was a transcription error when copying here

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Works now. Thank you